# Custom UISwitch Thumb Color with pattern image cause app crash (ARC)

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting, customization, uiswitch

I would like to customise my UISwitch Thumb by setting an image to his method "setThumbTintColor" but this cause app crash. If I simply set the color like that :

```
[switch setThumbTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

there's not problem.

But if I want to add an image like that :

```
    @property (nonatomic,strong) UIImage *imageThumb;
    @property (nonatomic,strong) UIColor *colorImageThumb;
    ...
    imageThumb = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myThumbImage.png"];
    colorImageThumb = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:imageThumb];
    [switch setThumbTintColor:colorImageThumb];
```

The app crash as soon as the UISwitch is dealloc (I'm working with ARC but this is the error message).

This thread seems to solve the problem but in an no-arc way. [Crashing while passing UIColor as argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095730/crashing-while-passing-uicolor-as-argument)

Any idea?

---

[EDIT]

The image name is thumb_wood.png.

The error message is an "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" error message.

The last methods in the mainThread tree are :

0 objc_msgSend

4 - [UISwitch dealloc]

5 - [MyUIViewController .cxx_destruct]

etc... destruct chain

Comment: What is your image named? What is the exact error you are seeing? What type of image are you trying to load?

Comment: I've edited my question to answer you.

Comment: Are you setting the image filename properly in your code? And is it in a directory accessible from your code?

Comment: I've just deleted an re added properly the image to be sure, the app is still crashing. Yes the folder is accessible.

Comment: @Zen I'm working with ARC

Comment: Yeah I missed it. What if you retain the `colorImageThumb` explicitly. Does it crashes then too?

Comment: How can I do that in ARC mode?

Comment: Same exact problem here. Using colorWithPatternImage as the switch's tint color causes this to happen.